# Adding classes using classList

Tags: javascript

probably easy but for some reason it doenst work.

I just try to add a class to some element in my code.

```
document.getElementById("test").classList.add("someclass")
```

However, if I check the code for the added class it doesn't appear anywhere. When I alert the class list of that element "someclass" shows up, just not in the dom (and doen't do any changes as well).

Any suggestions?

Thats pretty much the code:

```
<section id="vergleichen">
</section>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
               document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList.add("Test");
               alert(document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the code that produces your problem?

Comment: Can you provide some editable reproduction example? That's will be helpful.

Comment: just make sure your code will run after the element load in DOM

Comment: Added the code, really not much going on and that's why I dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

May your div have height 0 so you did not see visualize.

I tried to set class as

```css
#vergleichen{
 height: 100px;
}
.Test{
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="vergleichen">
</section>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList.add("Test");
       alert(document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It actually has content, I just didnt paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList.add("Test");
    alert(document.getElementById("vergleichen").classList);
}
```

```css
.Test{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<section id="vergleichen">
  <h1>This is text<h1>
</section>
```